# pandasql EOL error while scanning string literal

Tags: python, pandasql

I have the code below where I'm trying to use pandasql to run a sql query with sqldf.  I'm doing some division and aggregation.  The query runs just fine when I run it in r with sqldf.  I'm totally new to pandasql and I'm getting the error below, can anyone see what my issue is and suggest how to fix it?  I've also included some sample data.

Code:

```
import pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

ExampleDf=pysqldf("select sum(lastSaleAmount-priorSaleAmount)/sum(squareFootage) as AvgPric 
                              ,zipcode
                            from data
                            where priorSaleDate between '2010-01-01' and '2011-01-01'
                            group by zipcode
                            order by
                            sum(lastSaleAmount-priorSaleAmount)/sum(squareFootage) desc")
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-100-679165684772>", line 1
    ExampleDf=pysqldf("select sum(lastSaleAmount-priorSaleAmount)/sum(squareFootage) as AvgPric
                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Sample Data:

```
print(data.iloc[:50])


          id                       address    city state zipcode   latitude  \
0    39525749               8171 E 84th Ave  Denver    CO   80022  39.849160   
1   184578398             10556 Wheeling St  Denver    CO   80022  39.888020   
2   184430015           3190 Wadsworth Blvd  Denver    CO   80033  39.761710   
3   155129946           3040 Wadsworth Blvd  Denver    CO   80033  39.760780   
4      245107               5615 S Eaton St  Denver    CO   80123  39.616181   
5     3523925              6535 W Sumac Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.615136   
6    30560679              6673 W Berry Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.616350   
7    39623928                5640 S Otis St  Denver    CO   80123  39.615213   
8   148975825                5342 S Gray St  Denver    CO   80123  39.620158   
9   184623176         4967 S Wadsworth Blvd  Denver    CO   80123  39.626770   
10   39811456         6700 W Dorado Dr # 11  Denver    CO   80123  39.614540   
11   39591617               4956 S Perry St  Denver    CO   80123  39.628740   
12   39577604                4776 S Gar Way  Denver    CO   80123  39.630547   
13  153665665            8890 W Tanforan Dr  Denver    CO   80123  39.630738   
14   39868673           5538 W Prentice Cir  Denver    CO   80123  39.620625   
15  184328555           4254 W Monmouth Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.629000   
16   30554949              6600 W Berry Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.616165   
17   24157982              6560 W Sumac Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.614712   
18   51335315              5655 S Fenton St  Denver    CO   80123  39.615488   
19  152799217              5626 S Fenton St  Denver    CO   80123  39.616153   
20   51330641              5599 S Fenton St  Denver    CO   80123  39.616514   
21   15598828              6595 W Sumac Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.615144   
22   49360310              6420 W Sumac Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.614531   
23   39777745               4962 S Field Ct  Denver    CO   80123  39.625819   
24   18021201              9664 W Grand Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.625826   
25   39776096            4881 S Jellison St  Denver    CO   80123  39.628401   
26   29850085               5012 S Field Ct  Denver    CO   80123  39.625537   
27   51597934               4982 S Field Ct  Denver    CO   80123  39.625757   
28   39563379                4643 S Hoyt St  Denver    CO   80123  39.632457   
29   18922140              5965 W Sumac Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.615199   
30   39914328           9740 W Chenango Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.627226   
31   51323181           5520 W Prentice Cir  Denver    CO   80123  39.620548   
32    3493378            4665 S Garland Way  Denver    CO   80123  39.632063   
33    4115341           5466 W Prentice Cir  Denver    CO   80123  39.619027   
34   39639069              5735 W Berry Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.617727   
35  184333944            9015 W Tanforan Dr  Denver    CO   80123  39.631178   
36   18197471             4977 S Garland St  Denver    CO   80123  39.626080   
37   49430482            9540 W Bellwood Pl  Denver    CO   80123  39.624558   
38   39868648              5535 S Fenton St  Denver    CO   80123  39.617145   
39  143684222         3761 W Wagon Trail Dr  Denver    CO   80123  39.631251   
40  152898579               4850 S Yukon St  Denver    CO   80123  39.629025   
41   43174426              4951 S Ammons St  Denver    CO   80123  39.626582   
42   39615194  7400 W Grant Ranch Blvd # 31  Denver    CO   80123  39.618440   
43  184340029   7400 W Grant Ranch Blvd # 7  Denver    CO   80123  39.618440   
44    3523919                5425 S Gray St  Denver    CO   80123  39.618265   
45  151444231              6610 W Berry Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.616148   
46   19150871               4756 S Perry St  Denver    CO   80123  39.630389   
47   39545155           4328 W Bellewood Dr  Denver    CO   80123  39.627883   
48    3523923              6585 W Sumac Ave  Denver    CO   80123  39.615145   
49   51337334               5737 W Alamo Dr  Denver    CO   80123  39.615881   

     longitude  bedrooms  bathrooms  rooms  squareFootage  lotSize  yearBuilt  \
0  -104.893468         3        2.0      6           1378     9968     2003.0   
1  -104.830930         2        2.0      6           1653     6970     2004.0   
2  -105.081070         3        1.0      0           1882    23875     1917.0   
3  -105.081060         4        3.0      0           2400    11500     1956.0   
4  -105.058812         3        4.0      8           2305     5600     1998.0   
5  -105.069018         3        5.0      7           2051     6045     1996.0   
6  -105.070760         4        4.0      8           2051     6315     1997.0   
7  -105.070617         3        3.0      7           2051     8133     1997.0   
8  -105.063094         3        3.0      7           1796     5038     1999.0   
9  -105.081990         3        3.0      0           2054     4050     2007.0   
10 -105.071350         3        4.0      7           2568     6397     2000.0   
11 -105.040126         3        2.0      6           1290     9000     1962.0   
12 -105.100242         3        4.0      6           1804     6952     1983.0   
13 -105.097718         3        3.0      6           1804     7439     1983.0   
14 -105.059503         4        5.0      8           3855     9656     1998.0   
15 -105.042330         2        2.0      4           1297    16600     1962.0   
16 -105.069424         4        4.0      9           2321     5961     1996.0   
17 -105.069264         4        4.0      8           2321     6337     1997.0   
18 -105.060173         3        3.0      7           2321     6151     1998.0   
19 -105.059696         3        3.0      7           2071     6831     1999.0   
20 -105.060193         3        3.0      7           2071     6050     1998.0   
21 -105.069803         3        3.0      7           2074     6022     1996.0   
22 -105.067815         4        4.0      9           2588     6432     1996.0   
23 -105.099825         3        2.0      7           1567     6914     1980.0   
24 -105.106423         3        2.0      5           1317     9580     1983.0   
25 -105.108440         3        3.0      5           1317     6718     1982.0   
26 -105.099012         2        2.0      6            808     8568     1980.0   
27 -105.099484         2        1.0      6            808     6858     1980.0   
28 -105.104752         3        2.0      6           1321     6000     1978.0   
29 -105.062378         3        4.0      8           2350     6839     1997.0   
30 -105.107806         2        2.0      5           1586     6510     1982.0   
31 -105.058600         2        4.0      6           2613     8250     1998.0   
32 -105.101493         3        2.0      8           1590     7044     1977.0   
33 -105.057427         3        5.0      7           2614     9350     1999.0   
34 -105.059123         3        4.0      7           2107     6491     1998.0   
35 -105.099179         2        1.0      5           1340     6741     1982.0   
36 -105.103470         3        2.0      6           1085     6120     1985.0   
37 -105.104316         3        1.0      6           1085    13500     1981.0   
38 -105.060195         4        3.0      8           2365     6050     1998.0   
39 -105.036567         3        2.0      5           1344     9240     1959.0   
40 -105.081998         2        3.0      5           1601     6660     1986.0   
41 -105.087250         3        2.0      8           1858     6890     1986.0   
42 -105.079900         2        2.0      5           1603     5742     1997.0   
43 -105.079900         2        2.0      5           1603     6168     1997.0   
44 -105.061397         3        3.0      7           1860     6838     1998.0   
45 -105.069618         3        4.0      8           2376     5760     1996.0   
46 -105.038707         3        2.0      5           1355     9600     1960.0   
47 -105.042611         2        2.0      6           1867    11000     1973.0   
48 -105.069604         3        3.0      7           2382     5830     1996.0   
49 -105.059085         3        3.0      6           1872     5500     1999.0   

   lastSaleDate  lastSaleAmount priorSaleDate  priorSaleAmount  \
0    2009-12-17           75000    2004-05-13         165700.0   
1    2004-09-23          216935           NaN              NaN   
2    2008-04-03          330000           NaN              NaN   
3    2008-12-02          185000    2008-06-27              0.0   
4    2012-07-18          308000    2011-12-29              0.0   
5    2006-09-12          363500    2005-05-16         339000.0   
6    2014-12-15          420000    2006-07-07         345000.0   
7    2004-03-15          328700    1998-04-09         225200.0   
8    2011-08-16          274900    2011-01-10              0.0   
9    2015-12-01          407000    2012-10-30         312000.0   
10   2014-11-12          638000    2005-03-22         530000.0   
11   2004-02-02          235000    2000-10-12         171000.0   
12   2004-07-19          247000    1999-06-07         187900.0   
13   2013-08-14          249700    2000-09-07         217900.0   
14   2004-08-17          580000    1999-01-11         574000.0   
15   2011-11-07          150000           NaN              NaN   
16   2006-01-18          402800    2004-08-16         335000.0   
17   2013-12-31          422000    2012-11-05         399000.0   
18   1999-12-02          277900           NaN              NaN   
19   2000-02-04          271800           NaN              NaN   
20   1999-10-20          274400           NaN              NaN   
21   2007-11-30          314500           NaN              NaN   
22   2001-12-31          342500           NaN              NaN   
23   2016-12-02          328000    2016-08-02         231200.0   
24   2017-06-21          376000    2008-02-29         244000.0   
25   2004-08-31          225000           NaN              NaN   
26   2016-09-06          310000    2015-09-15         258900.0   
27   1999-12-06          128000           NaN              NaN   
28   2004-04-28          197000           NaN              NaN   
29   2011-08-11          365000    2004-08-04         365000.0   
30   2015-07-08          302000    2004-07-15         210000.0   
31   2000-02-10          425000    1999-04-08         396500.0   
32   2016-02-26          275000    2004-12-03         204000.0   
33   2005-08-29          580000    1999-09-10         398200.0   
34   2004-06-30          355000    2001-02-22         320000.0   
35   2015-05-26           90000    1983-06-01          80000.0   
36   2017-06-08          312500    2017-05-12         258000.0   
37   2001-04-27          184000    1999-11-10         164900.0   
38   2004-02-08          335000    2001-05-08         339950.0   
39   2016-10-17          290000           NaN          70200.0   
40   2010-09-02          260000    1998-04-14         189900.0   
41   2012-07-30          231600    2012-03-30              0.0   
42   2013-10-24          400000    2004-08-04         388400.0   
43   2004-11-19          350000    1998-10-05         292400.0   
44   2005-06-23          295000    2004-07-26         300000.0   
45   2009-06-24          404500    2000-05-04         304900.0   
46   1999-12-14          153500    1999-12-14         153500.0   
47   2004-05-25          208000           NaN              NaN   
48   2016-10-20          502000    2005-05-31         357000.0   
49   2013-04-05          369000    2000-08-07         253000.0   

    estimated_value  
0            239753  
1            343963  
2            488840  
3            494073  
4            513676  
5            496062  
6            514953  
7            494321  
8            496079  
9            424514  
10           721350  
11           331915  
12           389415  
13           386694  
14           784587  
15           354031  
16           515537  
17           544960  
18           504791  
19           495121  
20           495894  
21           496281  
22           528343  
23           349041  
24           367754  
25           356934  
26           346001  
27           342927  
28           337969  
29           500105  
30           353827  
31           693035  
32           350857  
33           716655  
34           493156  
35           349355  
36           348079  
37           343957  
38           504705  
39           311996  
40           391469  
41           418814  
42           502894  
43           478049  
44           475615  
45           521467  
46           366187  
47           386913  
48           527104  
49           497239
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the quotes to be able to read multiline string:

```
ExampleDf=pysqldf("""select sum(lastSaleAmount-priorSaleAmount)/sum(squareFootage) as AvgPric 
                              ,zipcode
                            from data
                            where priorSaleDate between '2010-01-01' and '2011-01-01'
                            group by zipcode
                            order by
                            sum(lastSaleAmount-priorSaleAmount)/sum(squareFootage) desc""")
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Wow that is a lot of quotes.  I'll up vote and accept your answer shortly when SO lets me.